# jqGrid Format Cell While You Type

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

Is it possible configure jqGrid to allow format cell while you type. I am trying to implement something like this [Money Mask](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/) jquery library functionality.

When users enter price values when editing cell, I want to the cell to format as they type.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working based off of [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg) answer to autocomplete within cell editing.

```
colNames: ["Name", "Price"],
colModel: [{
    name: "name",
    index: "name",
    },
    {
    name: "Price",
    index: "Price",
    editable: true,
    editoptions: {
        dataInit: function (elem) {
            $(elem).maskMoney();
            /*
            https://cdn.cdnhttps.com/cdn-libraries/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js
            http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/
            */
        }
    }
```